# Error sending bulk emails to users: Too many messages in this connection laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send bulk emails (approx. 5000) to subscriber. I am sending all emails in BCC and Mail::queue(). I am running command from console to trigger emails.

```
try {
$bccEmails = ['test@test.com', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'anb@hotmail.com', 'xyzz@yahoo.com'];

Mail::queue('Emails.Newsletter', $data, 
    function ($message) use ($bccEmails, $subject) {

      $message->from('no-reply@test.com', 'xyz.com')
              ->bcc($bccEmails)
              ->replyTo($this->adminEmail, $this->adminName)
              ->subject($subject);
});

} catch (Exception $ex) {
   Log::info("Email sending error: ".$ex->getMessage());
}
```

But i am getting error as below:

`"Expected response code 250 but got code "421", with message "421 too many messages in this connection"`

1. **How to resolve above issue ?**
2. **What is the best way to send bulk emails to users ?**

**Second question**: which one is the best approach. As mentioned above Mail:queue or Mail:send in loop as below:

```
$toEmails = ['test@test.com', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'anb@hotmail.com', 'xyzz@yahoo.com'];

foreach ($toEmails as $key => $email) {

   try {
    Mail::send('Emails.Newsletter', $data, 
    function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {

      $message->from('no-reply@test.com', 'xyz.com')
              ->to($email)
              ->replyTo($this->adminEmail, $this->adminName)
              ->subject($subject);
    });

  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    Log::info("Email sending error: ".$ex->getMessage());
    // If failed continue sending next email
  }

}
```

Using: Laravel 5.2, Shared hosting

Please help on this. Let me know if further details is required.

Answer (score 0):

1) a) Exim has a setting 'smtp_accept_max' which limits the number of messages allowed per connection. If you use WHM you can change this in exim configuration manager -> advanced editor. I have mine set to 2000

Description in whm:

> This option specifies the maximum number of simultaneous incoming SMTP calls that Exim will accept. It applies only to the listening daemon; there is no control (in Exim) when incoming SMTP is being handled by inetd. If the value is set to zero, no limit is applied. However, it is required to be non-zero if either smtp_accept_max_per_host or smtp_accept_queue is set. See also smtp_accept_reserve and smtp_load_reserve.
>
> A new SMTP connection is immediately rejected if the smtp_accept_max limit has been reached. If not, Exim first checks smtp_accept_max_per_host. If that limit has not been reached for the client host, smtp_accept_reserve and smtp_load_reserve are then checked before accepting the connection.

b) In Laravel AppServiceProvider boot method add the following so it looks like:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(2000, 1));
}
```

this will make SwiftMailer disconnect, pause for 1 second and reconnect after sending 2000 messages.

Basically just replace 2000 with the smtp_accept_max value you set in exim.

2) I send bulk mail with the above set up (But Laravel 5.5) and with database queue driver. Works fine :)

Comment: Since you're on shared hosting you likely cannot access 'smtp_accept_max', so ask your hosting provider what it is or just change the 2000 limit i use to 100 and test increasing from there

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.2 and shared hosting. So is it applicable for the same ?

Comment: Yes. Start with a lower number eg 100 and if it works increase it till it stops working.\Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 1));